# Plotting many solutions of FindRoot

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

To an earlier problem, @Rhermans provided the following solution:

```
With[{Pt = 0.5, σ = 0.1, S = 1}, 
   FindRoot[1/(6 σ^2 (-1 + w) w) S ((Log[Sqrt[3] σ + Pt] -
      Log[Pt + Sqrt[3] σ (1 - 2 w)]) Pt (Sqrt[3] σ + Pt) - (6 σ^2 + 
       Sqrt[3] σ (Log[-Sqrt[3] σ + Pt] + Log[Sqrt[3] σ + Pt] - 2 Log[Pt + Sqrt[3] σ (1 - 2 w)]) Pt + (-Log[-Sqrt[
          3] σ + Pt] + Log[Sqrt[3] σ + Pt]) Pt^2) w + 6 σ^2 w^2) == 0, {w, 0.5}]]
```

How can I proceed and create a Plot of many such solutions by letting Pt, say, vary while holding other variables constant?

Comment: `With[{σ = 0.1, S = 1}, ListPlot@Table[{Pt, w /. FindRoot[..]}, {Pt, 0., 1., 0.1}]]`?  We might need more details to give better help.

Comment: @Michael E2 This is almost what I had imagined. I had imagined (somehow) connecting solutions with a line such that (with enough precision, I guess) the observer could not tell if the solution was derived exactly from Solve or from FindRoot.

Comment: `ListLinePlot` instead of `ListPlot` or `ListPlot[Table[...], Joined ->True]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue) to create an interpolating function of `w[Pt]`. First, we construct the ODE:

```
eqn = Block[{σ=.1, S=1},
    1/(6 σ^2 (-1+w) w) S ((Log[Sqrt[3] σ+Pt]-Log[Pt+Sqrt[3] σ (1-2 w)]) Pt (Sqrt[3] σ+Pt)-(6 σ^2+Sqrt[3] σ (Log[-Sqrt[3] σ+Pt]+Log[Sqrt[3] σ+Pt]-2 Log[Pt+Sqrt[3] σ (1-2 w)]) Pt+(-Log[-Sqrt[3] σ+Pt]+Log[Sqrt[3] σ+Pt]) Pt^2) w+6 σ^2 w^2)==0
] /. w->w[Pt];
```

To use [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue), we need an initial condition:

```
w5 = w[.5] /. FindRoot[eqn /. Pt->.5, {w[.5], .5}]
```

> 0.409537

Using [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue):

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[eqn, Pt], w[.5]==w5}, w, {Pt, 0, 1}];
```

Visualization:

```
Plot[sol[t], {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange->All]
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm, `sol = NDSolveValue[{eqn, v'[Pt] == 1, v[0.5] == 0.5}, w, {Pt, 0, 1}]` also works, but if `v` is changed to `x`, it does not. Actually if the dummy variable name starts with x, y or z, it fails; otherwise, it succeeds (well, for as many as I checked).    I've used the `NDSolveValue`/`NDSolve` method with both ODEs and DAEs in answers several times on this site and so have you.  Every time it comes up again, I feel like there should be a suitable duplicate, but I have trouble finding one. (+1)

Answer (score 2):

I changed the code to automatically achieve the desired accuracy. Added a couple of pictures to illustrate the behavior of the function

```
f[Pt_, \[Sigma]_, S_] := 
 w /. Block[{$MinPrecision = 200, $MaxPrecision = 200}, 
   FindRoot[
    1/(6 \[Sigma]^2 (-1 + w) w) S ((Log[Sqrt[3] \[Sigma] + Pt] - 
           Log[Pt + Sqrt[3] \[Sigma] (1 - 2 w)]) Pt (Sqrt[
             3] \[Sigma] + Pt) - (6 \[Sigma]^2 + 
           Sqrt[3] \[Sigma] (Log[-Sqrt[3] \[Sigma] + Pt] + 
              Log[Sqrt[3] \[Sigma] + Pt] - 
              2 Log[Pt + 
                 Sqrt[3] \[Sigma] (1 - 2 w)]) Pt + (-Log[-Sqrt[
                    3] \[Sigma] + Pt] + 
              Log[Sqrt[3] \[Sigma] + Pt]) Pt^2) w + 
        6 \[Sigma]^2 w^2) == 0, {w, 1/2}, PrecisionGoal -> 200, 
    WorkingPrecision -> Automatic]]
Table[{Pt, f[Pt, 0.1`20, 1`20]}, {Pt, .5, 1, .01}]
{Plot[f[Pt, 1/10, 1], {Pt, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
  AxesLabel -> {"Pt", ""}], 
 Plot[f[1/2, \[Sigma], 1], {\[Sigma], 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
  AxesLabel -> {"\[Sigma]", ""}]}
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: I had imagined (somehow) connecting solutions with a line. Is that possible, or am I confined to using dots?

Comment: Added a couple of pictures to illustrate the behavior of the function